# I want to know if this is a good programming practise else how can i write the program more optimal and efficient

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I want to write the program of converting decimal to binary and then find number of consecutive 1s in it without using fuctions such as Integer.toBinary(), etc.
my program :

```
public class Practise {

static String decimalToBinary(int num) {
    String binaryN = "";
    while (true) {
        binaryN += num % 2;
        num = num / 2;

        if (num == 1) {
            binaryN += 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    String nBinary = "";
    for (int i = binaryN.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        nBinary += binaryN.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(nBinary);
    return nBinary;
}

static int consecutiveOnes(String binaryN) {
    int consecutive = 0;
    int max = 0;
    boolean isFreshStart = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < binaryN.length(); i++) {

        if (binaryN.charAt(i) == '1') {
            if (isFreshStart) {
                consecutive = 1;
                isFreshStart = false;
            } else
                consecutive++;

        } else {
            isFreshStart = true;

        }
        if (consecutive > max)
            max = consecutive;
    }
    return max;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    String binaryN = decimalToBinary(n);
    System.out.println(consecutiveOnes(binaryN));
}

}
```

Is my Program Optimal if not then how can if be more optimal ,thanks in advance.

Comment: looks ok, but the loop won't terminate for `num <= 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to count consecutive 1s,
then it's best not to convert into a binary string at all.

You can iterate over the bits using bit shifting:

```
int work = num;
while (work > 0) {
    int bit = work & 1;
    work >>= 1;
    // Todo: count consecutive 1s
}
```

This approach will use much less storage (essentially a single `int` instead of a `String`), and work much faster without creating additional objects and unnecessary intermediate type conversions.

Comment: thanks for the answer learnt alot from it but can you check whether my  counting  consecutive 1's method is optimal or not.

Comment: @Adibrajiwate my point was that no, it's not optimal. But let's say if I look only at `consecutiveOnes` that takes the bits as a `String`, the implementation of that method alone is OK in terms of performance, but it can be written in a simpler way that's easier to read: you could drop the flag variable `isFreshStart` and reduce some of the conditionals.